# Android app signing mechanism

Tags: android

To prevent frauds I have to verify server side, that application connecting to my server is not a fake. I was wondering If I can use built in  android signing mechanism? Maybe there is some kind of *unique* (different for each device) magic number that I can verify on each request?

Thank you for any suggestions.

m.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a different ID from the server to the device, so that every device owns a unique ID. You can create an algorithm that calculates different numbers.

Comment: Okay, this is about _identification_, it's not enough. Fake app can do the same. I need something that uses app signeture

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Identifying App Installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) on Android Developers Blog.

Comment: Okay, this is about _identification_, it's not enough. Fake app can do the same. I need something that uses app signeture

Comment: Theoretically, fake app can as well do whatever your legitimate app does. So it is up to you to design a mechanism that verifies the legitimacy. It would be worthwhile to read the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155316/how-to-verify-that-server-calls-are-being-made-from-the-app) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Basic Authentication coupled with SSL? Setup your web server to permit only authenticated requests. Code your app to pass Base64-encoded username/password with each HTTP request. Since it would be over SSL, so it would not be easy to get hold of the login credentials.

Comment: At first seems ok, but... I can (as a hacker) get client cert from original app and put in fake.

Comment: @MarcinOchocki I am not proposing to use the client cert. I am saying that you call your server-side APIs over HTTPS and also pass username/password to go through the Basic Auth settings on the webserver.