# Verify network connection comes from my app

Tags: security

My server must receive data from a number of devices who have downloaded my application through an app store or otherwise trusted channel. I need a method to verify that data my server receives is actually from these devices. The server does not have access to a list of these devices ahead of time.

What are some popular ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155316/how-to-verify-that-server-calls-are-being-made-from-the-app

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the platform. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10155686/47961) to the linked question offers the idea (of using SSL for authentication).

I'd like to add to that answer, that if the client has some API with non-exportable private keys (either hardware-based or encrypted like CryptoAPI certificate storage in Windows), then you can store client certificates there.