# How to share my service only to users who purchased my application in Google Play?

Tags: android, web-services, security, rest, google-play

I would like to publish my Android app in Google Play this application uses a service created by myself, for the sake of the example let's say it's a Java REST service hosted somewhere. Now i would like to provide this service with some authentication so that the only client able to invoke methods on it is application purchased on Google Play.

I would like the solution to be compatible even if user changes his device and downloads the application on other device using same Android Market username.

It would be great if user didn't have to provide some kind of credentials every time he launches the client, in other words the solution would be completely transparent for the end user.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155316/how-to-verify-that-server-calls-are-being-made-from-the-app

Answer (score 0):

If you just want that nobody who does not use your app is able to access your webservice, a very simple solution would be that the webservice requires a specific parameter which your app sends with every request.

Let's say the webservice requires the parameter "key" to be "secretkey". Let your app add this parameter to every request, so the webservice does not ignore the request. If someone tries to access your webservice, they won't provide the correct key-value pair and not get a response.

If, of course, you want to make sure that the user has PAID for your app, and not gotten the APK somewhere else, this does not work.

Comment: Wouldn't that be easy to detect? For example using java decompiler and just obtain those 2 strings. Or maybe catch the request using for example WireShark. Of course solution would be ideal if only users who paid for the app can use it.

Comment: I am not experienced with decompiling. But using HTTPS would make it much harder to catch and read the request on-the-fly.